# How can batch file read a text doc and move directories listed?

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of directories stored in a file called *test_text.txt*. I need to be able to run a batch file that will read the text from the file and move the directories that are listed in the text document to a new directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
echo

FOR  /D %%I in (test_text.txt) do move C:\users\%username%\desktop\dumb

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is this (making some assumptions that test_text.txt has valid directories in it):

```
SET LOGFILE=C:\logs\movelog.txt
REM Use /f to read the contents of a file, and %%i to reference the line you just read:
for /f %%i in (test_text.txt) do (
    move %%i C:\users\%username%\desktop\dumb >nul 2>&1
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%i : Move failed >> %LOGFILE%%
    ) else (
        echo %%i : Move successful >> %LOGFILE%
    )
)
```

**Edit**: Added error handling/reporting.  Note that the >nul 2>&1 bit is there to suppress the output from `move`.

**Edit 2**: Added explicit redirects to a logfile.

Comment: That code works perfectly! Thank you!  Is there a way to output the results of the move to a text file with the names that did and did not move?  Basically an error log.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer to reflect that.  You can run your batch file with `movedirs > logfile.txt` (assuming you called your batch file `movedirs`...)

Comment: The code works but the output only says Move successful it doesn't individually list each directory that was or was not successfully moved to a text file. Is there a way to make this happen? My code:                                                                for /f %%i in (test_text.txt) do move %%i C:\users\%username%\desktop\dumb >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (echo %%i : Move failed) else (echo %%i : Move successful) >>results.txt

Comment: Fixed.  Change the first line to set the location of your logfile, then **don't** use `> logfile.txt` when you call it.

Comment: Incidentally, if you find that this answer helps you, please mark it as "answered" by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer.